# What EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard means and how to solve it?

Tags: kernel, logs

I found this in my kernel logs:

```
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
```

What does it mean and how should I fix it?

```bsh
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Comment: Is there an actual problem to solve that would remain if you didn't have these lines in the logs? (I guess this comment is applicable to all your 7 recent questions).

Comment: I try to solve all issues reported